# UIWebView crashed when link with target="_blank" selected

Tags: iphone, jsp, uiwebview

I am using UIWebView to display web pages in my application. but when hyperlink with target="_blank" is get selected application terminate automatically.
                      
is there any way to avoid this crash.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, I found that if we set target of an `a` tag to `_self` we can avoid the crash easily. But still there is on restriction to this, as we can apply the Javascript in this method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

So before, selecting this link before loading the page crashed the application as no Javascript is applied.

If anybody knows solution, guide to me.

Thanks